# Count price variations in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a dataset I picked up. the objective is to count the number of variations of price per weekday.

```
       ID_CAR      DATE          Price
0       4389     2020-01-01      4000         
1       10012    2020-01-01      2000
2       1001     2020-01-01      5000         
3       4389     2020-01-02      4030     
4       10012    2020-01-02      2000
5       1001     2020-01-02      5040   
6       4389     2020-01-03      4030
7       10012    2020-01-03      2010
8       1001     2020-01-03      5060
```

Exemple of the result :

```
       ID_CAR      DATE          Price   Variation
0       4389     2020-01-01      4000         0
1       10012    2020-01-01      2000         0
2       1001     2020-01-01      5000         0  
3       4389     2020-01-02      4030         1
4       10012    2020-01-02      2000         0
5       1001     2020-01-02      5040         1
6       4389     2020-01-03      4030         1
7       10012    2020-01-03      2010         1
8       1001     2020-01-03      5060         2
```

There can be several weeks, the goal is to iterate every day of the week.

I really need your help to find the best modeling for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's `groupby` the dataframe on `ID_CAR` and `transfrom` the column `Price` with `factorize` to identify the distinct variations in `Price`:

```
df['Variation'] = df.groupby('ID_CAR')['Price'].transform(lambda s: s.factorize()[0])
```

---

```
   ID_CAR        DATE  Price  Variation
0    4389  2020-01-01   4000          0
1   10012  2020-01-01   2000          0
2    1001  2020-01-01   5000          0
3    4389  2020-01-02   4030          1
4   10012  2020-01-02   2000          0
5    1001  2020-01-02   5040          1
6    4389  2020-01-03   4030          1
7   10012  2020-01-03   2010          1
8    1001  2020-01-03   5060          2
```